# R Studio pauses running the code every time there is an error

Tags: rstudio

RStudio pauses every time there is an error, even when the error doesn't affect the output. Here is what I have tried to fix so far:

Change the settings:

Debug -> On Error > Message only

Tools -> Global Options and uncheck “Use debug error handler only when my code contains errors”.

Reinstall RStudio and R

Update: I reinstalled prior version of R studio and it solved the problem

Comment: Have you considered a simple `try({})` statement, lumping all of the error code into the curly brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing Ctrl+A to highlight the document and then Ctrl+Enter to run? It should execute all lines of code regardless of errors.

Comment: That's how I always run the code. But my RStudio has a problem. it's not working properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).